# Correctly escaping in snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently facing an issue where my snippet is not correctly rendered when used.

**Snippet**

```
  "Import": {
    "prefix": "import",
    "body": ["import ${1: { ${2:module} } } from \"${0:library}\";"],
    "description": "Import module (es6)"
  },
```

**The problem**

This is the first tab, as you can see it does not select the `}` for some reason. The other tabs are working fine. I've tried a couple of possibilities but they are not resolving the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the second '}' with '\'. The following works.

```
"body": ["import ${1:{ ${2:module} \\}} from \"${0:library}\";"],
```